# Bouncing multiple boxes animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm part way through this project that would allow multiple images to bounce around a viewport, but I'm having some issues and I'm truly stumped. The script should do the following;

1. Randomly position each image
2. Bounce each image around the `#alumni` box.

The problems I'm having are;

1. The images move together as one big block rather than firing out at random directions and being 'independent' of one another. When one image bounces from the corner, the whole block changes direction.
2. If an image loads in outside of the bounding box, the script gets jammed up and it will only move left/right or up/down along the side it's stuck on.
3. Images shouldn't be appearing outside of the `#alumni` box at all here

Here's the script;

```js
const container = document.getElementById("alumni");
let velX = 3;
let velY = 2;

// ====

function randomLeftTop(el, img) {
  const containerWidth = el.offsetWidth / 2;
  const containerHeight = el.offsetHeight / 2;
  const imageWidth = img.offsetWidth / 2;
  const imageHeight = img.offsetHeight / 2;
  return {
    left: Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerWidth - imageWidth)),
    top: Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerHeight - imageHeight)),
  };
}

// ====

function hitBox(el, bnd) {
  if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && velX < 0) {
    velX = -1 * velX;
    console.log(`velX`, velX);
  }

  if (el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth >= bnd.offsetWidth) {
    velX = -1 * velX;
    console.log(`velX`, velX);
  }

  if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && velY < 0) {
    velY = -1 * velY;
    console.log(`velY`, velY);
  }

  if (el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight >= bnd.offsetHeight) {
    velY = -1 * velY;
    console.log(`velY`, velY);
  }
}

// ====

function moveIt(el, bnd) {
  hitBox(el, bnd);
  el.style.left = `${el.offsetLeft + velX}px`;
  el.style.top = `${el.offsetTop + velY}px`;

  setTimeout(() => {
    moveIt(el, bnd);
  }, 25);
}

// ====

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // 1. Find all of our images
  const images = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  let image = null;

  // 2. Do some stuff to our images
  for (image of images) {
    const random = randomLeftTop(container, image);

    image.style.left = `${random.left}px`;
    image.style.top = `${random.top}px`;

    moveIt(image, container);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0;
}

#alumni {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Alumni Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="alumni">
    <div id="boxes">
      <div class="box"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x300" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="box"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x300" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="box"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x300" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="box"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="box"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x200" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Although it looks like it's running into some issues there so you can see a 'working' preview here:

https://hult-network.chrish-d.vercel.app/

And the source is also on GitHub should you want to clone it:

https://github.com/chrish-d/GSAP-Connected-Nodes/tree/non-gsap

(originally planned on using GSAP but trying it without now)

Comment: My head is spinning...  Very messy...  Ok:  
`image.setAttribute("style",...)` overrides previous ones, so only `top` remains.  
Use `image.style.setProperty("left", randomLeft)` - `randomLeft` is whatever you want 'left` to be.  
In `setRandomPosition` - why are you halving the width/height?

Comment: `function randomLeftTop(containerWidth, containerHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight) {  
  return {left:Math.floor(Math.random()*(containerWidth-imageWidth)), top:Math.floor(Math.random()*(containerHeight-imageHeight))};
}`  Then, say: `var random=randomLeftTop(800,600,100,100); image.style.setProperty("left", random.left); image.style.setProperty("top", random.top);`
Or, something similar.

Comment: Why `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"...` and then `<script src="./index.js" defer></script>` (deffer)?  
Why `./index.js` and not just `index.js`?

Comment: I like how you've wrapped the function in the `setTimeout`~

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to add position style for `alumni` - `absolute` or `relative`...

Comment: I see you've used `el.style.left = `${el.offsetLeft + velX}px`;` - nice - better (I think) than `image.style.setProperty("left", randomLeft)` that I wrote above.  
Why string literal?  
`el.style.left=el.offsetLeft+velX` is enough.  The `px` will be added by javascript.

Comment: Thanks @iAmOren I've added your suggestions. The image placement is working really nicely now, but the animation still isn't working.

Comment: I've updated my original answer with the updated code but the problems are;

1. The images move together as one big block rather than firing out at random directions and being 'independent' of one another. When one image bounces from the corner, the whole block changes direction.
2. If an image loads in outside of the bounding box, the script gets jammed up and it will only move left/right or up/down along the side it's stuck on.
3. Images shouldn't be appearing outside of the #alumni box at all here

Comment: Oh yeah and I halved the widths/heights to help keep the images within the `#alumni` boundary a little better, as they kept appearing outside of the box

Comment: For the images not to move all as a clump - Make an array of randomized velocities: one pair (x and y) for each image.